# Why does my click function not work inside of this SVG on mobile devices but it does on desktop?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, svg

I have 2 simple JS function's shown in this snippet:

```js
function ReplaceHeader(id,content) {
          var container = document.getElementById(id);
          container.innerHTML = content;
          }

 function ReplaceContent(id,content) {
          var container = document.getElementById(id);
          container.innerHTML = content;
          }
```

```css
.st0 {
            fill: #C6C8AB;
          }
          .st1 {
            clip-path: url("#SVGID_2_");
            fill: #C6C8AB;
          }
          .st2 {
            fill: #5362FF;
          }
          .st3 {
            fill: #2A4D5C;
          }
          .st4 {
            font-family: 'HalisR-Bold';
          }
          .st5 {
            font-size: 10px;
          }
          .st6 {
            enable-background: new;
          }
          .st7 {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #C6C8AB;
            stroke-width: 3;
          }
          .st8 {
            clip-path: url("#SVGID_4_");
            fill: none;
            stroke: #C6C8AB;
            stroke-width: 3;
            stroke-miterlimit: 10;
          }

path.active {
    stroke: #5362FF;
    stroke-width: 8px;
    paint-order: stroke;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
}
text.active tspan {
    fill: #5362FF !important;
}

.gd-globe a:hover > path {
    stroke: #5362FF;
    stroke-width: 8px;
    paint-order: stroke;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
}

.gd-globe a:hover > text tspan, .gd-globe a:hover > text {
    fill: #5362FF !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="gd-globe">
      <svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 485.1 359.6" style="enable-background:new 0 0 485.1 359.6;" xml:space="preserve">
        <!-- Click replace content JS -->
        
        <rect x="198.9" y="23.1" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -3.1406 167.3344)" class="st0" width="3" height="128.6"/>
        <rect x="284.3" y="208.6" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -109.2435 282.0108)" class="st0" width="3" height="128.6"/>
        <rect x="135.2" y="174.3" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -65.8929 192.5836)" class="st0" width="128.6" height="3"/>
        <rect x="224.5" y="185.1" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -47.3859 258.8714)" class="st0" width="128.6" height="3"/>
        <rect x="108.8" y="130.7" class="st0" width="132.5" height="3"/>
        <rect x="244.3" y="230.8" class="st0" width="135.3" height="3"/>
        <rect x="242.4" y="36.1" class="st0" width="3" height="290.2"/>
        <g>
          <defs>
            <rect id="SVGID_1_" x="2.9" y="26.3" width="474.9" height="312.5"/>
          </defs>
          <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
            <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_" style="overflow:visible;"/>
          </clipPath>
          <path
            class="st1"
            d="M240.3,338.8c-69.8,0-129.8-16.1-173.6-46.6C25.5,263.5,2.9,224.6,2.9,182.6c0-42.9,21.3-81.8,60-109.6
          c42.5-30.5,103.8-46.6,177.4-46.6c70.9,0,131.4,16.1,174.8,46.6c40.4,28.4,62.7,67.3,62.7,109.6c0,41.8-23.1,80.7-64.9,109.6
          C369.3,322.3,308,338.8,240.3,338.8z M240.3,29.3c-72.9,0-133.7,15.9-175.6,46.1C26.8,102.6,5.9,140.7,5.9,182.6
          c0,41,22.2,79.1,62.5,107.2c43.3,30.2,102.8,46.1,171.9,46.1c67.1,0,127.7-16.4,170.8-46.1c41-28.3,63.6-66.4,63.6-107.2
          c0-41.3-21.8-79.3-61.4-107.2C370.5,45.2,310.6,29.3,240.3,29.3z"/>
        </g>
        <path
          class="st2"
          d="M390.2,231.4c-0.1-58.8-47.7-106.5-106.5-106.5H244h-0.1h-0.5c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4,0.1c-3.1,0.5-5.5,3-5.8,6.2
        c0,0.1-0.1,95.2-0.1,95.2H204c-51.5,0-93.2-41.7-93.2-93.2S152.5,40,204,40h40c3.7,0.1,6.9-2.8,7-6.5s-2.8-6.9-6.5-7
        c-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5,0h-39.9c-59,0-106.7,47.8-106.7,106.8c0,58.9,47.8,106.7,106.7,106.7H244c3.7,0,6.8-3,6.8-6.8v-94.7h33
        c49.5,0,90.4,38.8,92.9,88.3c0.1,1.6,0.1,3.2,0.1,4.8c0,3.2-0.2,6.3-0.5,9.5c-4.7,47.5-44.8,83.7-92.6,83.5H244
        c-3.7,0-6.7,3-6.8,6.7c0,2.9,1.9,5.5,4.7,6.5l0,0c0.6,0.2,1.3,0.3,2,0.3h39.8C342.6,337.7,390.2,290.1,390.2,231.4"/>
        
        <!-- Social Entrepreneurs -->
        <a href="javascript:ReplaceHeader('header','Social Entrepreneurs'); javascript:ReplaceContent('content','some content'); ">
          <path class="st3" d="M331.4,150.6c3.8,0,6.8-3.1,6.8-6.8s-3.1-6.8-6.8-6.8c-3.8,0-6.8,3.1-6.8,6.8l0,0
        C324.6,147.5,327.7,150.6,331.4,150.6"/>
          <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 355.2294 118.67)" class="st6">
            <tspan x="0" y="0" class="st3 st4 st5">SOCIAL</tspan>
            <tspan x="-24.8" y="12" class="st3 st4 st5">ENTREPRENEURS</tspan>
          </text>
        </a>

      </svg>
    </div>

<h5 id="header" class="h2" style="font-size:18px; text-align:left;">header</h2>
        <span class="copy" id="content">title</span>
```

and some href's with the function coded inline.  The hrefs are around SVGs.  I have created a Codepen with all the code:

https://codepen.io/maniac123/pen/PXovZq

On click of the href, it should be changing the values in a h2 with the id "header" and a span with the id "content".

This all works perfectly on desktop, but on an iPhone device and android, it isn't pulling in the values.  The h2 and span aren't changing.

Comment: There's no jQuery here. You might try attaching the handler properly using Javascript (eg `addEventListener`) rather than HTML attributes

Comment: Removed jQuery, apologies I had some jQuery in there originally but removed it as it wasn't related to this problem.

Comment: @Liam, I thought I had... what is missing?

Comment: Added them in, didn't think they were required, sorry!

Comment: No there is one h2, and one span with one single unique ID.  there are differnet <a href=""> with the JS function in, with different content that should change the h2 and span on click.  it works FINE on desktop, only on mobile devices it doesn't work.

Comment: To be completley clear, I've added a second link in the snippet.

Comment: I have tested on iPhone, but my client tells me her Android device also does not display them either...   The link in snippet above doesn't show on my mobile device, it defaults the snippet box back to [code] boxes

Comment: Yes it works for me too in a codepen.  I think the issue is that I have the links in SVG's.  I neglected to mention this originally, because I didn't think it was relevant, and I was trying to simplify the post.  I have setup a codepen here:  https://codepen.io/maniac123/pen/PXovZq  this is the full code I have, it doesn't work here on mobile.

Comment: An [`a` tag in an svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/a) is not the same as `a` HTML a tag. I'm not sure it's guarenteed to honour href with javascript in it like your doing. Probably use an onclick event and see if that helps. I'm not an SVG expert though.

Comment: Hi I have tested the [codepen](https://codepen.io/maniac123/pen/PXovZq) on Android with Chrome and Firefox and both work correct. However in Firefox on desktop is it not working. Please checkout my answer if it works on your mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proble comes from `javascript:someFunction` the SVG is not the problem.
It seems that `javascript:someFunction` does not work in all browsers.
This means that not only mobile is suffering from it.
Please take a look at: [a href=javascript:function() in firefox not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38856853/a-href-javascriptfunction-in-firefox-not-working).
Here is also an intresting discusion: [JavaScript function in href vs. onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070760/javascript-function-in-href-vs-onclick).

To answer your question I would use the onlick shown below:

```js
// Made the functions to 1 function because the content was the same
function ReplaceContent(id,content) {
  var container = document.getElementById(id);
  container.innerHTML = content;    
}
```

```html
<a href='#' onclick='
ReplaceContent("header", "New header")
ReplaceContent("text", "More Lorem ipsum...")
' >test</a>
<h2 id='header'>Header</h2>
<p id='text'>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetur adipiscing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

I believe that the next snippet is clearer for reuse:

```js
function LinkReplace() {
  // Now you do not need to fiddle in the HTML for JS functions
  ReplaceContent("header", "New header")
  ReplaceContent("text", "More Lorem ipsum...")
}

function ReplaceContent(id,content) {
  var container = document.getElementById(id);
  container.innerHTML = content;    
}
```

```html
<a href='#' onclick='LinkReplace()' >test</a>
<h2 id='header'>Header</h2>
<p id='text'>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetur adipiscing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

With SVG:

```js
function LinkReplace() {
  // Now you do not need to fiddle in the HTML for JS functions
  ReplaceContent("header", "New header")
  ReplaceContent("text", "More Lorem ipsum...")
}

function ReplaceContent(id,content) {
  var container = document.getElementById(id);
  container.innerHTML = content;    
}
```

```css
.st0 {
  fill: #C6C8AB;
}
.st1 {
  clip-path: url("#SVGID_2_");
  fill: #C6C8AB;
}
.st2 {
  fill: #5362FF;
}
.st3 {
  fill: #2A4D5C;
}
.st4 {
  font-family: 'HalisR-Bold';
}
.st5 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
.st6 {
  enable-background: new;
}
.st7 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #C6C8AB;
  stroke-width: 3;
}
.st8 {
  clip-path: url("#SVGID_4_");
  fill: none;
  stroke: #C6C8AB;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

path.active {
    stroke: #5362FF;
    stroke-width: 8px;
    paint-order: stroke;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
}
text.active tspan {
    fill: #5362FF !important;
}

.gd-globe a:hover > path {
    stroke: #5362FF;
    stroke-width: 8px;
    paint-order: stroke;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
}

.gd-globe a:hover > text tspan, .gd-globe a:hover > text {
    fill: #5362FF !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="gd-globe">
      <svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 485.1 359.6" style="enable-background:new 0 0 485.1 359.6;" xml:space="preserve">
        
        <rect x="198.9" y="23.1" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -3.1406 167.3344)" class="st0" width="3" height="128.6"/>
        <rect x="284.3" y="208.6" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -109.2435 282.0108)" class="st0" width="3" height="128.6"/>
        <rect x="135.2" y="174.3" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -65.8929 192.5836)" class="st0" width="128.6" height="3"/>
        <rect x="224.5" y="185.1" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -47.3859 258.8714)" class="st0" width="128.6" height="3"/>
        <rect x="108.8" y="130.7" class="st0" width="132.5" height="3"/>
        <rect x="244.3" y="230.8" class="st0" width="135.3" height="3"/>
        <rect x="242.4" y="36.1" class="st0" width="3" height="290.2"/>
        <g>
          <defs>
            <rect id="SVGID_1_" x="2.9" y="26.3" width="474.9" height="312.5"/>
          </defs>
          <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
            <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_" style="overflow:visible;"/>
          </clipPath>
          <path
            class="st1"
            d="M240.3,338.8c-69.8,0-129.8-16.1-173.6-46.6C25.5,263.5,2.9,224.6,2.9,182.6c0-42.9,21.3-81.8,60-109.6
          c42.5-30.5,103.8-46.6,177.4-46.6c70.9,0,131.4,16.1,174.8,46.6c40.4,28.4,62.7,67.3,62.7,109.6c0,41.8-23.1,80.7-64.9,109.6
          C369.3,322.3,308,338.8,240.3,338.8z M240.3,29.3c-72.9,0-133.7,15.9-175.6,46.1C26.8,102.6,5.9,140.7,5.9,182.6
          c0,41,22.2,79.1,62.5,107.2c43.3,30.2,102.8,46.1,171.9,46.1c67.1,0,127.7-16.4,170.8-46.1c41-28.3,63.6-66.4,63.6-107.2
          c0-41.3-21.8-79.3-61.4-107.2C370.5,45.2,310.6,29.3,240.3,29.3z"/>
        </g>
        <path
          class="st2"
          d="M390.2,231.4c-0.1-58.8-47.7-106.5-106.5-106.5H244h-0.1h-0.5c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4,0.1c-3.1,0.5-5.5,3-5.8,6.2
        c0,0.1-0.1,95.2-0.1,95.2H204c-51.5,0-93.2-41.7-93.2-93.2S152.5,40,204,40h40c3.7,0.1,6.9-2.8,7-6.5s-2.8-6.9-6.5-7
        c-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5,0h-39.9c-59,0-106.7,47.8-106.7,106.8c0,58.9,47.8,106.7,106.7,106.7H244c3.7,0,6.8-3,6.8-6.8v-94.7h33
        c49.5,0,90.4,38.8,92.9,88.3c0.1,1.6,0.1,3.2,0.1,4.8c0,3.2-0.2,6.3-0.5,9.5c-4.7,47.5-44.8,83.7-92.6,83.5H244
        c-3.7,0-6.7,3-6.8,6.7c0,2.9,1.9,5.5,4.7,6.5l0,0c0.6,0.2,1.3,0.3,2,0.3h39.8C342.6,337.7,390.2,290.1,390.2,231.4"/>
        
        <!-- Social Entrepreneurs -->
        <a href='#' onclick='LinkReplace()'>
          <path class="st3" d="M331.4,150.6c3.8,0,6.8-3.1,6.8-6.8s-3.1-6.8-6.8-6.8c-3.8,0-6.8,3.1-6.8,6.8l0,0
        C324.6,147.5,327.7,150.6,331.4,150.6"/>
          <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 355.2294 118.67)" class="st6">
            <tspan x="0" y="0" class="st3 st4 st5">SOCIAL</tspan>
            <tspan x="-24.8" y="12" class="st3 st4 st5">ENTREPRENEURS</tspan>
          </text>
        </a>

      </svg>
    </div>

<h2 id='header'>Header</h2>
<p id='text'>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetur adipiscing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

Comment: This is possibly correct but you need to use the OPs example code as his issue is specifically about SVGs and there is no SVG in this answer

Comment: @Liam I added SVG snippet

Comment: Thanks, changing to onclick did indeed fix the issue.